# How to list the kernel Device Tree

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, device-tree

I am using an embedded Arm with a Debian build. How does one list the compiled devices from the device tree? I want to see if a device is already supported.

For those reading this, the "Device Tree" is a specification/standard for adding devices to an (embedded) Linux kernel.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The device tree is exposed as a hierarchy of directories and files in `/proc`. You can `cat` the files, eg:

```
find /proc/device-tree/ -type f -exec head {} + | less
```

Beware, most file content ends with a null char, and some may contain other non-printing characters.

Answer (score 60):

If dtc is available on your platform (else, install the `device-tree-compiler` package), you can use:

```
dtc -I fs /sys/firmware/devicetree/base
```

Comment: If /sys/firmware/devicetree/base doesn't exist on your system, instead try `dtc -I fs /proc/device-tree`