# How do I find out what is loading a given kernel module?

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, armbian

I an using Armbian on an orange pi zero SBC

```
uname -a  
Linux orangepi 4.19.57-sunxi #5.90 SMP Fri Jul 5 17:58:43 CEST 2019 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

This is in relation to displaying Armbian output on an LCD module

lsmod gives me this:

```
$ lsmod | grep fb
fb_ili9340             16384  0
fbtft_device           40960  0
fbtft                  28672  2 fbtft_device,fb_ili9340
```

I am not sure at this point but I think fb_ili9340 should not be running (that is, it is not the chipset used in the the current LCD I am working on, although it is possible that my current LCD is compatible with/is a clone of the ili9340).

Is there any way to find out when the fb_ili9340 module is getting loaded? There is another file that I made manually

```
/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf  
fbtft  
fbtft_device
```

so I can sort of see why fbtft and fbtft_device are loaded. I also have a

```
/etc/modprobe.d/fbtft.conf  
options fbtft_device rotate=90 name=waveshare32b busnum=1 gpios=dc:3,reset:0 speed=32000000
```

file, which I think just specifies the parameters to use when loading the fbtft_device module. But I don't know where fb_ili9340 is coming from. What is the proper way to find out this information?

Comment: Since ARM systems like the various Pi's tend not to have autoprobeable buses, their hardware detection and module autoloading relies on a device tree blob file loaded along with the kernel by your bootloader.[See this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/289563/258991): make sure the `device-tree-compiler` package is installed, then run `dtc -I fs /sys/firmware/devicetree/base` or perhaps `dtc -I fs /proc/device-tree` if the `/sys/firmeware/devicetree/base` does not exist. If results don't match reality, you'll need to customize your device tree or its overlays.

Comment: @telcoM I don't know if I have device-tree-compiler (is it a command like "armbian-add-overlay" ?) but dtc --ver shows `Version: DTC 1.5.0`. Should having dtc be enough?